# Typescript - "this" keyword error

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript

I'm doing a simple example here where i'm using the Phaser library.

```
    module GameName {
    class GameName extends Phaser.Game{

        constructor(width?:number, height?:number){
            super(width, height, Phaser.AUTO, 'PhaserDemo', {create:this.create});
        }

        create() {
            this.state.add("Preloader", Preloader, true);
        }
    }

    window.onload = () => {
        new GameName(1280, 720);
    }
}
```

So i got an error while compiling the Typescript on the "this" keyword here {create:this.create}

I cant understand what i'm doing wrong. I just called the constructor of the Phaser.Game class into the constructor of my GameName class and i'm adding the create function of the Phaser.Game class as parameter to the super-constructor.

Error: ***'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the `this.create` function in an anonymous function

```
constructor(width?:number, height?:number){
  super(width, height, Phaser.AUTO, 'PhaserDemo', {
    create: () => this.create(),
  });
}
```

- Removes the immediate call to `this`(?)
- Fixes `this` possibly being undefined inside the create callback, see: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript

Comment: Yes this way the error is gone and it compiles but it doesnt enter the function at all. 

But if i do it this way ->

 constructor(width?:number, height?:number){
            super(width, height, Phaser.AUTO, 'PhaserDemo', {create: () => {
                this.state.add("Preloader", Preloader, true);
            }});
        }
    }


It works just fine.